# nested menu created using jQuery, CSS and HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a navbar using jQuery with multilevel nesting.

When I hover on the main menu instead just displaying the first list all the nested lists are displayed and I can't figure out why.

Here is my jQuery

```
(function($) {

        //  cache nav;
             var nav = $("#topNav");

             //add indicators and hovers to submenu parents;
             nav.find("li").each(function() {
                 if (this.find("ul").length > 0) {  


                //   show subnav on hover
                     $(this).mouseenter(function() {
                         var ullist = $(this).find("ul");
                         ullist.stop(true, true).slideDown();

                         ullist.removeClass("sublinks");
                     });

                //   hide submenus on exit
                    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
                        var ullist = $(this).find("ul");
                        ullist.stop(true, true).slideUp();
                        ullist.addClass("sublinks");
                    });
                 }
            });

        })(jQuery);
```

and my css:

```
nav > ul > li > a > img {
width:60px;
  height:60px;
 }

nav ul ul ul
{
left:100px;
top:-1px;
}

.submenu{
display:none;
}

.sublinks li {
display:none;
}


.social li > a > img{
    width:40px;
height:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
(function($) {
             var nav = $("#topNav");
               nav.find("li").each(function() {
                 if ($(this).find("ul").first().length > 0) {  //find first ul only

                     $(this).mouseenter(function() {
                         var ullist = $(this).find("ul").first();  //find first ul only
                         ullist.stop(true, true).slideDown();

                         ullist.removeClass("sublinks");
                     });

                    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
                        var ullist = $(this).find("ul").first();  //find first ul only
                        ullist.stop(true, true).slideUp();
                        ullist.addClass("sublinks");
                    });
                 }
            });
        })(jQuery);
```

Comment: The problem is still there. See xetecx.comxa.com

Comment: look at the console error.. I have updated code.. try that and check there is no error in console